# Is it possible to write an "all-or-nothing" CSS rule?

Tags: css

Imagine the scenario:
A user has an email client that has limited support for CSS.
(It either strips content, blocks linked CSS, sanitizes the email body before delivery, whatever.)

I want to apply a rule that e.g. transforms the visual of a link to shape it like a button with a gradient background and white text.

Some email clients accept the color: setting to set the text white, but strip the background.
This causes the link to have the white color, but having no background, it would stand against the white background of the email body, resulting in an unreadable link.

Is it possible to create a CSS rule that is only effeective if all rules can be applied?

like, "set (color AND background) OR do nothing"?

```
.all-or-nothing(set all or none) {
 color: #fff;
 background:linear-gradient(...);
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try the `@supports` at-rule, though I'd imagine many mail clients will not support it.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@supports

```
@supports (color: #fff) and (background: linear-gradient(...)) {
   .all-or-nothing {
      color: #fff;
      background: linear-gradient(...);
   }
}
```

Comment: Looks like it should work on browsers that support this feature. 
However, on webmail clients that could strip part of the content, it don't think it would work. I think this one is the best that can be done though, thanks!